# Pass Data from iOS query to Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, watchkit

I run a `Parse` query in my iOS app `TableViewController.m`.

**I need to ask the iOS app for that query data from my WatchKit extension `InterfaceController.m`**

How would I go about this using **`openParentApplication(_:reply:)`** + **`handleWatchKitExtensionRequest(_:reply:)`**?

`TableViewController.m` (iOS)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        // GMT Date from Phone
        NSDate *gmtNow = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"GMT Now: %@", gmtNow);

        // Query Parse
        PFQuery *query = [self queryForTable];
        [query whereKey:@"dateGame" greaterThanOrEqualTo:gmtNow];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSMutableArray *localMatchup = [@[] mutableCopy];

                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    // Add objects to local Arrays
                    [localMatchup addObject:[object objectForKey:@"matchup"]];

                    // App Group
                    NSString *container = @"group.com.me.off";
                    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

                    // Matchup
                    [defaults setObject:localMatchup forKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                    NSArray *savedMatchup = [defaults objectForKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                    NSLog(@"Default Matchup: %@", savedMatchup);
                    savedMatchup = matchupArray;
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                });

            }
        }];
    }
```

`AppDelegate.m` (iOS)

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {

NSString * request = [userInfo objectForKey:@"requestString"];
if ([request isEqualToString:@"executeMethodA"]) {

        // GMT Date from Phone
        NSDate *gmtNow = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"GMT Now: %@", gmtNow);

        // Query Parse
        PFQuery *query = [self queryForTable];
        [query whereKey:@"dateGame" greaterThanOrEqualTo:gmtNow];

        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSMutableArray *localMatchup = [@[] mutableCopy];

                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    // Add objects to local Arrays
                    [localMatchup addObject:[object objectForKey:@"matchup"]];

                    // App Group
                    NSString *container = @"group.com.me.off";
                    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:container];

                    // Matchup
                    [defaults setObject:localMatchup forKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                    NSArray *savedMatchup = [defaults objectForKey:@"KeyMatchup"];
                    NSLog(@"Default Matchup: %@", savedMatchup);
                    savedMatchup = matchupArray;
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                });
                    reply(@{@"success:": @true});

            }
        }];
    }
             // Assuming this is where I'd do the reply?
             // Not sure what would go here for the reply though?
reply(@{@"success:": @false});

}
```

`InterfaceController.m` (WatchKit)

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"executeMethodA"]; // This string is arbitrary, just must match here and at the iPhone side of the implementation.
NSDictionary *applicationData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[requestString] forKeys:@[@"theRequestString"]];

[WKInterfaceController openParentApplication:applicationData reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
    // What would I put here?
    NSLog(@"\nReply info: %@\nError: %@",replyInfo, error);
}];
```

I'm using Objective-C.  Will add any extra info needed, thanks!

Comment: As a side note, you are doing heavy work in application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:. Remember that the iOS app might be backgrounded when this delegate is called.
Add [self beginBackgroundTask]; in the beginning of the delegate and end it with [self endBackgroundTask];. This will allow longer background execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the Parse query in your AppDelegate method and package it in an NSDictionary and call `reply(queryDict);` The `replyInfo` dictionary in your InterfaceController will be populated with queryDict.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer!  I updated my question with a bunch of code filling in the blanks there... I'm still not totally there, can you help out with that?  I guess I'm not sure exactly how to do the `reply(queryDict)` in my specific code, and where the `replyInfo` would go in my InterfaceController code?  Thanks!!

Comment: I have the `Parse` query in my AppDelegate method, but in terms of packaging it in an `NSDictionary` how would I go about adding an `NSDictionary` named `queryDict` from the `matchupArray` that I get from the original `Parse` query?

Comment: Hoping you can help me finish this out, if you get a chance to check in on this and respond, that would mean a lot, thanks!!

Comment: Been crazy busy. I'll try to get back to this today. Quick note: try reading the docs and googling for tutorials. There's lots out there on this topic.

Comment: Awesome, I've been checking them out but will keep checking more out, and look forward to your response!  Seriously thanks for the help so far tho